# Long Notification Title in Android gets cropped when the app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

[image: Here is the Inshorts App Notification screenshot]We are pushing the notifications from Web App built in React JS. The notification title has around 95 characters and gets cropped when received on the phone. How do we wrap the title like in Inshorts App? We don't have any issues with when the app is in the foreground.

here is our React JS code to push the notification:

```
message = {
            notification: {
              title:"Long title with 95 characters",                  
              seoLink:"google.co.in",               
               image: "abc.jpg",            
              content_available: 'true'
            },           
            data: { 
            title:"Long title with 95 characters",           
            body: "body msg",                         
            seoLink:"google.co.in",             
               image: "abc.jpg",                
            },
            to: fcmToken
          };
```

This is the code we are using in Android Native:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(image)
                .setContentText(title)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setVibrate(vibrate)
                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: what u mean by `wrap the title like in Inshorts App` ?

Comment: There is an app called Inshorts. we need a notification is similar way.

Comment: Please attach the screenshot of ur desirable outcome

Comment: Added. we need text notification text wrapped like in the screenshot. Thanks

Comment: You can try `setContentText` to a random shorter text,but `setStyle` to your long long title(means set style remain the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a custom layout, you can apply `NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle` to your notification.

Create a custom xml file called `notification_small.xml`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  //here for the wrap content for the title
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/notification_title"
    android:id="@+id/notification_title"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title" />
```

Then build your Notification like this:

```
// Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_large);

// Apply the layouts to the notification
Notification customNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout) 
        .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
        .build();
```

You can read more about Custom notification layout here :

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification

For your problem that in background:

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642386/4332049)

Comment: Thank you so much.This is absolutely working fine for the app when it is in foreground but still not getting how to get title wrapped when app is killed or is in background

Comment: how ur notification look like now?

Comment: bro read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642386/4332049, remove the notification payload,just left the data payload

Comment: yes,read that. we are using FCM to send the notification. we need both the payloads while sending through firebase,only data payload doesn't work. we have tried it. we don't get notification without notification payload

Comment: FCM only support notification payload.. But if u have notification payload,then your custom notification appearance in device wont work..Therefore you have to choose either one..

Comment: That's what I am thinking. Is there any other cloud messaging service which serves our purpose?

Comment: What I suggest is, you send all the notification from your own,but not from firebase dashboard.. Means that,you build your own interface(form),then send the request ur own server to send the request to Firebase by using `data_payload`,see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message. By that,you can only set `data_payload` in ur app.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. managed to remove notification payload and wrap the text. your suggestion helped us.

Comment: nice bro..happy coding